# 3D scatter plot with crosses

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, style

I would like to do a 3D scatter plot with cross (x or +) markers instead of dots for each point. So far I'm using the following command:

```
p = ListPointPlot3D[points, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[0.01]]]
```

and it produces a proper 3D plot, but I can't find how to change the data markers from points to anything else (in my case, crosses). Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You could use `Graphics3D`, e.g. `Graphics3D[Text["+", #] & /@ dat]` where `dat` is your dataset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively to ubpdqn's suggestion, and in order to preserve the styling and default options of `ListPointPlot3D` I propose this solution:

```
ListPointPlot3D[RandomReal[10, {20, 3}]] /. Point -> Map[Text["+", #] &]
```

The trick is in this replacement rule:

```
/. Point -> Map[Text["+", #] &]
```

Comment: More generally, one can use `Inset[]`.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

@LLlAMnYP : one more question, how could you then modify the color/size of the markers?

Comment: EDIT: I figured out that `/. Point -> Map[Text[Style["+", Large, Bold, Red], #] &]` does the trick

Answer (score 9):

Just to illustrate:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[Text[marker, #] & /@ data],
 {marker, {"+", "x", Style["+", Red], Style["+", Bold]}}, 
 Initialization :> (data = RandomReal[1, {100, 3}])]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the "manipulate" command I just discovered. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
InputForm[ChemicalData["Methane", "MoleculePlot"]]
```

[image]

```
moleculePlot[poiints_] := Show[Graphics3D[
 {
  Translate[ 
     GraphicsComplex[
       {
        {0.0115361, -0.00644059, -0.0023318}, 
        {-6.98724, 109.314, 19.6968}, 
        {-53.4044, -24.1997, -94.6041}, 
        {-46.6211, -55.8814, 84.2109}, 
        {107.001, -29.2263, -9.30131}, 
        {-3.48785195, 54.653779705, 9.8472341},
        {-26.69643195, -12.103070295, -47.303215900000005}, 
        {-23.30478195, -27.943920295, 42.104284099999994}, 
        {53.50626805, -14.616370295, -4.651820900000001}}, 
       {
        {RGBColor[0.65, 0.7, 0.7], 
           Sphere[2, 24.],
           Sphere[3, 24.], 
           Sphere[4, 24.], 
           Sphere[5, 24.]
        }, 
         {RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 0.4], 
           Sphere[1, 34.]}, 

         {RGBColor[0.65, 0.7, 0.7], 
           Cylinder[{6, 2}, 15.], 
           Cylinder[{7, 3}, 15.], 
           Cylinder[{8, 4}, 15.], 
           Cylinder[{9, 5}, 15.]}, 
         {RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 0.4], 
           Cylinder[{1, 6}, 15.], 
           Cylinder[{1, 7}, 15.], 
           Cylinder[{1, 8}, 15.], 
           Cylinder[{1, 9}, 15.]}}], #]
       }
   ] & /@ (500*poiints)]
```

>

```
 somePoints = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 4}, {1, 1, 
5}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 
1}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 3}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 
2}, {1, 4, 3}, {1, 4, 4}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 5, 1}, {1, 5, 2}, {1, 5, 
3}, {1, 5, 4}, {1, 5, 5}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 1, 
4}, {2, 1, 5}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 4}, {2, 2, 
5}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 
1}, {2, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 3}, {2, 4, 4}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 5, 1}, {2, 5, 
2}, {2, 5, 3}, {2, 5, 4}, {2, 5, 5}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 
3}, {3, 1, 4}, {3, 1, 5}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 
4}, {3, 2, 5}, {3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 4}, {3, 3, 
5}, {3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 2}, {3, 4, 3}, {3, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 5, 
1}, {3, 5, 2}, {3, 5, 3}, {3, 5, 4}, {3, 5, 5}, {4, 1, 1}, {4, 1, 
2}, {4, 1, 3}, {4, 1, 4}, {4, 1, 5}, {4, 2, 1}, {4, 2, 2}, {4, 2, 
3}, {4, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 5}, {4, 3, 1}, {4, 3, 2}, {4, 3, 3}, {4, 3, 
4}, {4, 3, 5}, {4, 4, 1}, {4, 4, 2}, {4, 4, 3}, {4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 
5}, {4, 5, 1}, {4, 5, 2}, {4, 5, 3}, {4, 5, 4}, {4, 5, 5}, {5, 1, 
1}, {5, 1, 2}, {5, 1, 3}, {5, 1, 4}, {5, 1, 5}, {5, 2, 1}, {5, 2, 
2}, {5, 2, 3}, {5, 2, 4}, {5, 2, 5}, {5, 3, 1}, {5, 3, 2}, {5, 3, 
3}, {5, 3, 4}, {5, 3, 5}, {5, 4, 1}, {5, 4, 2}, {5, 4, 3}, {5, 4, 
4}, {5, 4, 5}, {5, 5, 1}, {5, 5, 2}, {5, 5, 3}, {5, 5, 4}, {5, 5, 
5}};
```

>

```
moleculePlot[somePoints]
```

Comment: Nice, but hardly germane.

Comment: Quite creative but a little bit more bulky than what I was expecting :)

Answer (score 3):

A variation of LLlAMnYP's method that performs better is to use [`Translate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html).  Compare:

```
gr = ListPointPlot3D[ RandomReal[10, {8000, 3}] ];

gr /. Point -> Map[Text[Style["+", Bold, Red], #] &]

gr /. Point[x_] :> Translate[Style[Text["+"], Bold, Red], x]
```

On my system the first method takes 2.70 seconds to render, while the second takes only 0.08 second.  Further interactive rotation of the second graphic will be found to be significantly smoother.